# Ping general faliure on windows server 2008 r2 after vpn setup attempt

Tags: server, vpn, ping, windows-server-2008-r2

So I tried to give our server a VPN role by installing the role and setting it up. Turned out the router does not support VPN connections and now I can not ping the server or access it through rdp. When 8 ping my PC it says general failure. When I ping the server the request times out .I reset ip TCP and flushed the winsock but it did not help. Deinstalled the role but still did not work. What should I do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Disabled the remote access service and it worked!